# How to set up tablet to use a local DNS server thru VPN rather than Google's DNS?

Tags: windows, asus-eee-pad-transformer, vpn, dns

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise server running in our home network. It has VPN functionality installed and fully working.

If I connect with a computer, the computer will get right DNS servers. If I connect with Android tablet (Asus Transformer Prime), the tablet will still use Google's DNS servers.

The problem with this is that I can't resolve local website addresses such as intranet. Getting the access to that site is more than necessary.

I want the (non-rooted) Android tablet to use the DNS servers provided by the VPN server.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You can do this from server side. As all DNS queries are going thru server, mapping Google DNS IP with your DNS IP would work..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can solve this issue either from the Android side or from the Windows side:

### From the Android side

1. Tap your device "menu" button, and select "settings";
2. Tap "Wireless & networks";
3. Tap "Wi-Fi settings";
4. Tap your device "menu" to bring up extra options and select "advanced";
5. Tap "Use static IP";
6. Fill in your local network static IP details and dns server details;
7. Tap your device "menu" to bring up extra options and select "save".

[image: Ip Settings Screen Shot]

---

### From the Windows side

1. Open the DNS management;
2. [Add a new Forward Lookup Zone](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771566.aspx#BKMK_winui) for the Google DNS and set a Host A record to your local IP.

Comment: I believe the Android settings you give are valid for Android 2.3+ (which might well be OK for the OP). However, these appear to have changed under Android 4.0 (which I've added in my answer).

Answer (score 4):

This is really a continuation of @Zuul's answer, to cover the DNS settings in Android 4.0+ (ICS), which is a little harder to find IMO. AFAIK Zuul's answer covers Android <2.3 settings.

### From the Android side (Android 4.0+ ICS)

1. Settings
2. WiFi (click on word "WiFi", not ON/OFF switch)
3. Press and hold (long tap) your wireless network until dialog pops up
4. Select "Modify Network"
5. Check "Show advanced options" checkbox at the bottom
6. Switch "IP settings" to "Static"
7. Fill in your local network static IP details and DNS server details
8. Tap "Save"

*(Whoever made long-taps a standard interface feature is a dummy!)*