# Custom DNS server not resolving wildcards

Tags: dns

I've setup my WiFi connection on my Galaxy S7 to use a [custom DNS server](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/26699/247965). My PC runs a DNS server at `192.168.0.100` and serves a few `A` records:

```
home.local    192.168.0.100
shed.local    192.168.0.101
*.shed.local  192.168.0.102
```

When I run `tracert` on my PC (192.168.0.100) it correctly resolves `home.local`, `shed.local` and `*.shed.local`.

Using PingTools I ran `tracert` on my phone. `home.local` and `shed.local` both resolve correctly to their respective addresses.

However the `*.shed.local` yields:

> Unknown host

Is there some difference in implementations of `DNS` between Windows and Android?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you cannot specify wildcards in /etc/hosts in linux (and therefore Android). People in Linux world have moved on to dnsmasq, I'm not sure what is the equivalent on Android. You'll have to work around it (maybe use proxy or some other setup?)

Comment: I am using a custom DNS server. I was able to make it work by mimicking the results returned from my 3rd party domain name server. The reason that it works on `Windows` is that for some reason it accepts a wildcard answer from the DNS server (whereas the `hosts` file also doesn't allow wildcards on `Windows`). To make it work on Android I had replace the single wildcard answer with a virtual `CNAME` record (based on the requested domain) pointing to an `A` record which I add as a second answer. This record points to the actual IP.